# Ayuda en C# para Acomodar nodos

Tags: c#

Hola amigos si pudieran ayudarme estoy haciendo un programita en C# q detecta los ficheros borrados y copiados de las memorias q se inserten en la pc, ahora mismo me va quedando asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera q la parte de los ficheros con los respectivos tamaños de los ficheros me quedaran acomodados de esta forma mas o menos ya q dependieendo de la cantidad de caracteres q tenga el nombre de archivo es la posicion donde me queda en este caso el 512 MB q es el tamaño y quisiera q todos los tamaños quedaran en el mismo lugar. Gracias de antemano,Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto es winform o wpf? lo que parece la segunda imagen es algun tipo de lista con columnas. intentaste algo?

Comment: Ya resolvi , es simplemente que hay q cambiarle el estilo de la letra a uno q sea monospace o fixed height para q cada caracter tenga el mismo ancho, es por eso q no me salian acomodados